# How to split a string of email addresses

Tags: python, python-re

I have strings with email addresses which I want to split into individual addresses:

```
import re

emails = "person1@gmail.comperson2@gmail.comperson3@gmail.com"

re.split("(.com)", emails)
#['person1@gmail', '.com', 'person2@gmail', '.com', 'person3@gmail', '.com', '']

#Expected result: ["person1@gmail.com", "person2@gmail.com", "person3@gmail.com"]
```

Comment: I don't see how that can be done. Is it "person1@gmail.com" then "person2@gmail.com" or "person1@gmail.co" and "mperson2@gmail.com"? You'd need to restrict domain names that it works with.

Comment: Where did this come from that there are no delimiters between the addresses? Maybe you can fix it at that source.

Comment: Are the email addresses guaranteed to belong to .com domains? Doesn't seem very realistic to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A positive look behind should give you what you're looking for when used with `re.split`.

```
>>> re.split(
...   r"(?<=\.com)", 
...   "person1@gmail.comperson2@gmail.comperson3@gmail.com"
... )
['person1@gmail.com', 'person2@gmail.com', 'person3@gmail.com', '']
```

You then just need to filter the empty string out.

Of course, any solution to this will be fragile, as legitimate email addresses may contain the string `.com` (or other top level domains) other than at the end of the email address.

Answer (score 0):

If all the emails end with `.com` you can use `re.findall()` to find all strings ending with `.com`.

```
>>> emails = "person1@gmail.comperson2@gmail.comperson3@gmail.comjohn.comte@yahoo.com"
>>> re.findall(r'[^@]+?@[^@]+?\.com', emails)
['person1@gmail.com', 'person2@gmail.com', 'person3@gmail.com', 'john.comte@yahoo.com']
```

Of course, in the real world there are lots of email addresses that aren't in the `.com` TLD. I don't think there's a reasonable solution that will work for more general collections of emails.

It also won't work if any of the email domains have `.com` in a subdomain, e.g. `foobar@bar.comma.com` will be matched as `foobar@bar.com`.

Comment: What if an email is `john.comte@gmail.com` or similar?

Comment: Exactly why the premise for this question does not scale or generalize and the problem needs to be solved at the source of this data.

Comment: @giusti Good point, we actually have someone with that laste name in our company.

Comment: @giusti I've revised it to search for the `@` and require that `.com` be after it.